# Matplotlib: change graph size but not the image size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am not sure how you do this: I create a figure of 4,4; when I display the graph, it takes most of the space; and I cannot see my X ticks.

So I did try to change the size of the graph only; but I don't see how this can be accomplished. I can change the whole size of the figure, but I don't see a way to say "make the picture 4,4 and the graph 4,2", so I have enough space at the bottom for x ticks labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The figure size is determined by the argument `figsize` which you can provide e.g. to `plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))` or `plt.subplots(figsize=(4,4))`.
What you are asking for is to adjust the size of the `axes` inside the figure.
There are several ways to do this.

1. Using `plt.tight_layout()` at the end of your script will tell matplotlib to adjust the size of the axes automatically to best fit into the figure. This works well in most standard cases but may also produce unwanted results in some others.
2. Using [`plt.subplots_adjust()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) which takes the following arguments: `left, bottom, right, top,  wspace, hspace`. Those parameters control the margin of the subplots inside the figure. So the case where you want more space below the figure, try something like `subplots_adjust(bottom=0.4)`.
3. Adding the axes dimensions manually using [`fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) where `left, bottom, width, height` are in figure units ranging from 0 (bottom left) to 1 (top right). In this case you can try something like `fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.8])`.